# ZF2 conflicts layout with same name

Tags: php, layout, module, zend-framework2, twig

I'm trying the framework ZF2 and I try to do very independant modules like bundles in SF2.

I've got ZfcTwig to have Twig to render my views. This worked until I've created a second module.

```
-Application (default module)
-Admin
  -view
     index.twig
  -layout
     base.twig
-Blog
  -view
     index.twig
  -layout
     base.twig
```

The problem is that my Blog layout extend the Admin base layout then !

I've done my structure layout based on http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2

So in both Module.php I've this:

```
public function init($moduleManager)
{
    $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
    $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        $controller->layout('layout/base.twig');
    }, 100);
}
```

Plus I don't understand why I've to define twice the layout, one time in the init function of Module.php, the second on extend function of twig views.

For sure its work if I've different names.

And I see for this module: https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts
But I think it should be possible without this to have really independant module since its the philosophy of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ZfcTwig works in "zf way", using the two-step view pattern.
If you want to use the original twig system (for extends), you must specify it in your config file.

It is well commented :

```
/**
* If set to true disables ZF's notion of parent/child layouts in favor of
* Twig's inheritance model.
*/
        'disable_zf_model' => true,
```

This way, you will control yous layouts with `extends` instructions.

Comment: It's already at true by default I already seen this line so I don't understand why I cant control directly with Twig

Comment: I'm not using it "the twig way", but i think that if this your case, then changing the layout in Module.php is of no use. The Twig's "extends" instruction is the one that will be used. I think this has to do with the template_map of the view_manager configuration. If the name is the same, it will resolve to the last file found in merged configuration.